# como aplicar la funcion reduce de python sobre una lista de una clase

Tags: python, class, programación-funcional

estoy aprendiendo un poco de poo y programacion funcional en python. En uno de los ejercicios que se me pide hacer es crear una clase tecnologia con ciertos atributos entre ellos el costo de estos y luego de crear una lista de 25 objetos debo manejar estos con programacion funcional y debo ocupar la funcion *reduce* para sacar el promedio entre todos los objetos de la lista. Intente esto

```
functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,lista.costo)
```

Pero me tira error. Dice: *'list' object has no attribute 'costo'*
He intentado varias cosas pero tampoco me funcionan. Por favor ayuda

Comment: no tendrás que usar tambien `map()`? (aparte de que la suma no es igual al promedio)

Comment: si, solo que se me olvido poner la division despues, pero el problema que cuando intento "recorrer" por asi decirlo lista.costo con alguna de las funciones me tira error

Comment: deberías colocar lo que tiene la variable lista

Answer (score 2):

Lo que debes tener es una lista de objetos, entonces x e y son objetos tipo tecnologia:

```
suma= functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x.costo+y.costo,lista)
```

Comment: Intente lo que djisite, crei que funcionaria, pero ahora dice:  int' object has no attribute 'costo', de hecho probe imprimir un solo costo de la lista para ver si el problema venia de antes, pero al parecer no es asi, tambien cambie el nombre del atributo y arrojaba lo mismo :(

Comment: El problema debe ser el constructor de la clase tecnología. ¿Cómo tienes implementado el constructor de la clase?